# classList.remove() peforms worse than className string manipulation

Tags: javascript, browser

For removing a class from an element,

```
elem.classList.remove("test");
```

seems to perform worse than

```
var removeCssClass = function(elem, cName) {
    var a = " " + elem.className + " ",
    b = a.indexOf(" " + cName + " ");

    if (b >= 0) {
       elem.className = (a.substr(0, b) + " " + a.substring(b + cName.length + 1, a.length)).trim()
    }
}
removeCssClass(elem, "test");
```

Quick bench https://jsbench.me/yhkmn56aox/1

On both Chromium and Firefox, I'm getting that the string manipulation version is faster. Somewhat surprising to me given that `classList.add()` is way faster than `elem.className += " someClass"`. I'm realizing I have no real understanding of the abstractions going on.

> Chromium DOMTokenList implementation:
> https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/dom/DOMTokenList.cpp
>
> Firefox DOMTokenList implementation:
> https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/base/nsDOMTokenList.cpp

I'm not sure how I would even begin trying to understand why one version is faster than the other. I'm assuming the JS string manipulation is done "within JS" (executed by v8/SpiderMonkey) but the final assignment to `elem.className` is a binding/interop. Likewise, I'm assuming `elem.classList.remove()` is simply binding to the above implementations.

To knowledge, none of the browser handling/processing of the added/removed classes comes into play until after JS stops executing - so it can't be explained by any later processing by the browser as part of the re-render process. (Is this correct?)

How can I get a look under the hood to get and get a better understanding of what is going on?

Comment: _"How can I get a look under the hood"_ - How much deeper do you want to dig? You already have the source code o.O

Comment: Your test is flawed. `removeCssClass` doesn't set anything, it stops at the `indexOf` line. If you do add the `test` class after each iteration both will perform at the same speed (classList being even a bit faster on my FF).

Comment: Isn't this one of those cases where the time taken to ask this question is VASTLY larger than any time savings you'd get from the "more optimised" code? Sure, I ran the tests - it said `.remove()` was 17% slower. It still estimated *over 2 million operations a second*. Are you in a situation where you perform millions of class removals every second and you need to optimise the fractions of a **micro**second that each take? That's before even venturing that the comparison is flawed. It's faster *only when there is nothing to remove*.

Comment: @Andreas - I've managed to find the source code for DOMTokenList, yes. But there are abstractions between JS code calling ".classList.remove()" and this code getting executed.

Comment: @Kaiido I'm aware. I'm not holding on to this specific example. I've tested all kinds of variations and, for my machine, `removeCssClass` is performing better.
I'm aware of my "benchmarks" not being worth much - I've just gotten interested in how I could go about getting a deeper understanding what is going on.

Comment: @VLAZ Again, this is probably poor communication on my part. I'm aware and agree with "premature optimization is the root of all evil". I'm interested in getting a better understanding of things work - JS executing, interop with the browser provided APIs, and perhaps some understanding of (post-JIT) the instructions executed for each. I'm interested in learning - forget whether I arrived at this point for the right/wrong reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that your tests are not equivalent.

- Not sure what the benchmarking site does, but i do not think it re-adds the HTML after each test, so you are only really testing the early exit of each code
- On my machine, with firefox, i get the `classList` as better performing
- For duplicate classes your code will only remove the first, while `.remove` will remove all of them

Comment: Also, as Kaiido mentions, the tests don't *actually* remove a class. Both attempt to remove a non-existing class, so this test tells us which noop is faster.

Comment: See comments above. Poor communication on my part. These "benchmarks" are indeed meaningless in so far as being used to decide whether to use one method over the other for all cases, and in any the performance really doesn't matter.
My aim was to give an example/context as to how (for no good reason) I've become interested in gaining a better understanding of what is going on with browser JS code - I guess all of it has to be JIT'd and executed by (for example) v8, but there must be some sort of interop layer calling the native code I've linked.
My aim is learning, not performance benefits.